Adding underscores to specific letters in attribute-driven label using ArcGIS Pro
I need to make labels that contain different formatting for specific characters to represent pronunciation.  Specifically, I need to underscore some letters in a label but not all.
The attribute values of the features do not contain the underscores as they are just a text value with no formatting.  This underscore will change depending on the feature, so it would make sense to add the underscore to the attribute value instead of having to adjust the formatting on an individual character on a label-by-label basis.
Is there a way to do that in the attribute value?
I am suspecting typing in the Unicode/ASCII value for an underscore version of that letter, if one exists, might be the way but I don't know how to achieve that.
I have sorted out how to get some special characters by using Word to type special symbols and then copy/pasting them into the attribute table to get things like an accented E (é) but I don't see any characters with built-in underscores. Perhaps a different font might have those?

Open the Windows app Character Map, and search for macron or low line in the Searh for box at the bottom.  These two search options should show you available Unicode characters that have underscores

You should be able to copy/paste these characters.  If you have a way of typing in Unicode values, then the Character Map also tells you the Unicode in the status bar at the bottom.
